# how to pass a function from child to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Basically I have a function is my child component, I would like to pass this function as a prop and call it my parent component.

```
 function parent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onclick={handleAbort}></button>
    </div>
  );
}


 function child() {

  const handleAbort=() =>{
    console.log('hello')
  }
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: To keep the right structure of React components (as I understood it's React) would be better to implement that function in parent component, if there is no way use Context for example)

Comment: also have a look this: https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useImperativeHandle

Answer (score 0):

If both of these components are in the same file, and the function is not tied to any hooks, then define it outside the component. This way, you don't need to pass it through the component tree as a prop and it does not get redefined on re-renders.

```
const handleAbort = () => {
  console.log('hello');
};

function parent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onclick={handleAbort}></button>
    </div>
  );
}

function child() {
  return <div></div>;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is not in the same file, this is just an example in fact @damonholden

Comment: could you please modify the question then to provide a more accurate example as there's no way to guarantee a good answer here if we have to guess your code structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass props from child to parent. what you can do is rendering the child in the parent component, and pass the function with props to the child. something like:

```
function Parent() {

  const handleAbort=() =>{
    console.log('hello')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Child handleClick={handleAbort} />
    </div>
  );
}


function Child({handleClick}) {

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}></button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you should try and pass from Parent to Child, what I think you may be trying to do is get a *value* from the Child to the Parent, which is often the case.  In that case you still pass the function from the Parent to the Child, but pass a *value* from the Child to the Parent via args of the function - e.g.

```
function Parent() {
  const handleAbortClick = (msg) => (e) => {
    console.log(msg)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Child onAbortClick={handleAbortClick} />
    </div>
  );
}


 function Child({ onAbortClick }) {  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onAbortClick('hello')}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-haze-dj8rr3?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean something like this?

```
function Parent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child dataToParent={(msg) => console.log(msg)} />
    </div>
  );
}


 function Child({dataToParent}) {

  const handleAbort=() =>{
    dataToParent('hello')
  }
  return (
    <div>
       <button onclick={handleAbort}></button>
    </div>
  );
}
```